# Logic for Jquery filtering through multiple categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I can't wrap my head around the logic here.

My JQuery:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div.filter-groups').find('input:checkbox').live('click', function () {
            $('.general').hide();
            $('div.filter-groups').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('.general').hide();
                $('div.general.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
        });
    });</script>
```

My check boxes:

```
    <div class="filter-groups">
                            <div class="filter-label">Price:</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Tier1">$100,000-$160,000</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Tier2">$160,000-$200,000</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Tier3">$200,000-$250,000</div>
                            <div class="filter-label">Number Of Rooms:</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Rooms3">3 Bedroom</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Rooms4">4 Bedroom</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Rooms5">5 Bedroom</div>
                            <div class="filter-label">Square Footage:</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Foot1">1,200-1,600</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Foot2">1,600-2,000</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Foot3">2,000+</div>
                            <div class="filter-label">Neighborhoods:</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="CityView">City View</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="HeritageHills">Heritage Hills</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="HillsideTerrace">Hillside Terrace</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="LonesomeDove">Lonesome Dove</div>
                            <div class="filter"><input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" rel="Tradewinds">Tradewinds</div>
                        </div>
```

The script works in that if you click on a checkbox it will show the div that contains the class that matches the "rel=" of that checkbox.

This works except that if I check the first price filter and the first neighborhood filter it will show the home that is in that neighborhood even though it belongs to the second price filter.

I need this script to take into account all of the filter sections when displaying the result. This question has been asked a few times but they are using a different method for  Any suggestions?

jsfiddle where I can't get my working code to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonathanSumner90/nh8vr1kp/

the web page where it works but not the way I'm trying to figure out here:

http://www.bluehavenhomes.com/floor-plans?hs_preview=1SQuQUzB-2347415373

---

Comment: Could you provide a working JSFiddle please.

Comment: I'd love to but for some reason when i transfer the code into jsfiddle it doesn't work.

Comment: To get your fiddle going ... use the proper jQuery version => `.live()` is deprecated and changed to `on()` since 1.5 or 1.6 I think. [like this perhaps](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/0dtqk4fs/)?

Comment: How are your result divs and classes?

Comment: I have edited my post to include the jsfiddle that i can't get to work and the link to the page where it works up to the point that I have it.

Comment: Inanda I'm not sure what you mean but the results do what they are supposed to except that it will always show the results for the lowest checkbox clicked regardless of whether it meats the class requirements of any check boxes checked above it.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a built-in function called `.filter()` in jQuery, which does what you want to achieve.

```
var checkboxes = $('div.filter-groups').find('input:checkbox'),
    general = $('.general');

function filterCheckboxes(ev){
    var rel = $(ev.currentTarget).attr('rel');

    general.hide().filter('.' + rel).show();
}

checkboxes.on('click', filterCheckboxes);
```

To fix your multiple checked checkboxes issue, you can filter the `:checked` state in all your `checkboxes` and for each `rel` apply the filter.

```
function filterCheckboxes(){
    var checked = checkboxes.filter(':checked');

    general.hide();
    $.each(checked, function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

        general.filter('.' + rel).show();
    });
}
```

Hope this is as intended.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/0dtqk4fs/)**

Word of advise: Use `data-` attributes instead of `rel` to be more expressive and/or to combine multiple filters on a single checkbox.

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="price" value="" data-filter="Tier1" />
```

**js**

```
var rel = $(this).data('filter');
```

Comment: This works but it still shows the divs relevant to all of the checked boxes instead of the divs relevant only to the boxes that are checked.  Also when i uncheck all of the boxes all of the divs are gone.?